# SSIS Performance drop when adding parameters

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis

I'm using an OLE DB Source in SSIS to pull data rows from a SQL Server 2012 database:

```sql
SELECT item_prod.wo_id, item_prod.oper_id, item_prod.reas_cd, item_prod.lot_no, item_prod.item_id, item_prod.user_id, item_prod.seq_no, item_prod.spare1, item_prod.shift_id, item_prod.ent_id, item_prod.good_prod, item_cons.lot_no as raw_lot_no, item_cons.item_id as rm_item_id, item_cons.qty_cons
FROM item_prod
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_cons on item_cons.wo_id=item_prod.wo_id AND item_cons.oper_id=item_prod.oper_id AND item_cons.seq_no=item_prod.seq_no AND item_prod.lot_no=item_cons.fg_lot_no
```

This works great, and is able to pull around 1 million rows per minute currently. A left outer join is used instead of a lookup due to much better performance when using no cache, and both tables may contain upwards of 40 million rows.

We need the query to only pull rows that haven't been pulled in a previous run. The last run row_id gets stored in a variable and put at the end of the above query:

```sql
WHERE item_prod.row_id > ?
```

On the first run, the parameter will be -1 (to parse everything). **Performance drops between 5-10x by adding the where clause** (1 million rows per 5-10 minutes). What is causing such a significant performance drop, and is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: Compare the execution plans. I assume they are different. I would look at making your filter dynamic and disabling it when it's initial load (parameter = -1) and enabling it otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, SSIS creates a stored procedure when executing a query with parameters. This was discovered by looking at the execution in SQL Server Profiler.

As a result, there was a performance hit, which I believe is [related to parameter sniffing](http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Pages/2011-April-Issue/Parameter-Sniffing-Problem-with-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedures.aspx).

I changed the source to use a `SQL Query from Variable` and built my query using an expression instead, and this fixed the performance.

**Edit:** The following are the commands seen in SQL Server Profiler when executing the question's code with the `where` parameter:

```sql
exec [sys].sp_describe_undeclared_parameters N'SELECT item_prod.wo_id, item_prod.oper_id, item_prod.reas_cd, item_prod.lot_no, item_prod.item_id, item_prod.user_id, item_prod.seq_no, item_prod.spare1, item_prod.shift_id, item_prod.ent_id, item_prod.good_prod, item_cons.lot_no as raw_lot_no, item_cons.item_id as rm_item_id, item_cons.qty_cons
FROM item_prod
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_cons on item_cons.wo_id=item_prod.wo_id AND item_cons.oper_id=item_prod.oper_id AND item_cons.seq_no=item_prod.seq_no AND item_prod.lot_no=item_cons.fg_lot_no
WHERE item_prod.row_id > @P1'

declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 int',N'SELECT item_prod.wo_id, item_prod.oper_id, item_prod.reas_cd, item_prod.lot_no, item_prod.item_id, item_prod.user_id, item_prod.seq_no, item_prod.spare1, item_prod.shift_id, item_prod.ent_id, item_prod.good_prod, item_cons.lot_no as raw_lot_no, item_cons.item_id as rm_item_id, item_cons.qty_cons
FROM item_prod
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_cons on item_cons.wo_id=item_prod.wo_id AND item_cons.oper_id=item_prod.oper_id AND item_cons.seq_no=item_prod.seq_no AND item_prod.lot_no=item_cons.fg_lot_no
WHERE item_prod.row_id > @P1',1
select @p1

exec [sys].sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT item_prod.wo_id, item_prod.oper_id, item_prod.reas_cd, item_prod.lot_no, item_prod.item_id, item_prod.user_id, item_prod.seq_no, item_prod.spare1, item_prod.shift_id, item_prod.ent_id, item_prod.good_prod, item_cons.lot_no as raw_lot_no, item_cons.item_id as rm_item_id, item_cons.qty_cons
FROM item_prod
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_cons on item_cons.wo_id=item_prod.wo_id AND item_cons.oper_id=item_prod.oper_id AND item_cons.seq_no=item_prod.seq_no AND item_prod.lot_no=item_cons.fg_lot_no
WHERE item_prod.row_id > @P1',N'@P1 int',1
```

Since I'm not entirely sure what the above generated code does, there may be other related commands that I missed. Originally, I assumed SSIS variables would be inserted into the query, but the introduction of the @P1 parameter led me to look at stored procedure implications instead.

Comment: Could you provide a reference where SSIS creates a stored procedure? I didn't see that in the referenced article

Comment: @billinkc It wasn't part of the article, the article is only relevant after finding out a stored procedure is being executed (rather than a query with the inserted variable, which is what I expected). I'll reproduce the results and update my answer.

Comment: @billinkc I've added the profiler results. I'd be interested in your opinion on if this is correct, since I'm decently new to SSIS.